# How to add the tags automatically before started the build creation?

Tags: build, devops, azure-pipelines

I have setup the build and release definitions for my web application in VSTS. Whenever I commit the code then automatically start the build process, after build succeed I manually add the tags like shown in below figure.

[image]

But I want to add the build tags before started the build creation only. So, how can I add the tags automatically before started the build creation?

Answer (score 2):

- It seems you are using CI build, so if you want to add tags automatically, you can use **pre-push hook** in local git repo.
- Or if it’s ok for you to add tags after build, you can **set in build definition**. In Get sources step -> show Advanced settings -> select Always for Tag sources -> specify Tag format -> save.

  [image]

---

**A sample example for pre-push hook** (`.git/hooks/pre-push`), to add a tag with increment of tag version and the version format is `major.minor`, the number is not bigger then `9`:

```
#!/bin/sh

temp1=0
temp2=0


for tag in $(git tag)
do
{
  IFS=. read -r major minor <<< "$tag"
  if [ $((major-temp1)) > 0 ]

  then
  {
    temp1=$major
    temp2=$minor

  }
  elif [ $major == $temp1 ]
  then
  {
    if [ $((minor-temp2)) > 0 ]
    then
    temp2=$minor
    else
    {
      temp1=$temp1
      temp2=$temp2
    }
    fi
  }

  fi
}
done
if [ $temp2 != 9 ]
then
  temp2=$((temp2+1))
else
  temp1=$((temp1+1))
fi
nexttag=$temp1"."$temp2
git tag -a $nexttag -m $nexttag
```

Comment: Thanks @Marina, if it is possible tell me some example code on how to set pre-push hook in local git repo.

Comment: I added an example of pre-push hook in the end of my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: It's just an example to explain how pre-push works. You can develop the script based on your requirement. If you have any problem during develop the script, you can post another question.